# Selenium XPath multiple attributes including text

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Here is the HTML I'm dealing with

```
<a class="_54nc" href="#" role="menuitem">
    <span>
        <span class="_54nh">Other...</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

I can't seem to get my XPath structured correctly to find this element with the link. There are other elements on the page with the same attributes as `<a class="_54nc">` so I thought I would start with the child and then go up to the parent.

I've tried a number of variations, but I would think something like this:

```
crawler.get_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="_54nh"][contains(text(), "Other")]/../..')
```

None of the things I've tried seem to be working. Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, more cleaner is `//*[.='Other...']/../..` and with `.` you are directly pointing to the parent element

In other scenario, if you want to find `a` tag then use css `[role='menuitem']` which is a better option if `role` attribute is unique

Answer (score 0):

how about trying this

```
crawler.get_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="_54nc"][./span/span[contains(text(), "other")]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

crawler.get_element_by_xpath('//a[@class='_54nc']//span[.='Other...']');

**This will search for the element 'a' with class as "_54nc" and containing exact text/innerHTML "Other...". Furthermore, you can just edit the text "Other..." with other texts to find the respective element(s)**

Comment: This one doesn't work. It still can't find the element.